# Prove whether it is a injection, surjection or a bijection

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

$f$ : R x R -> R x R ; $f(x, y)= (x+y,2y)$

I apologize for formatting. I really need help on this question. I think it is a bijection because I cannot find a counterexample. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: It is a linear transformation because the mapping can be shown with a matrix. Does this help?

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{R}$?
How can you show a function is an injection? How about a surjection?

Comment: Yes, it is a bijection. Can you try proving it?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: There are at least two straightforward ways to prove that it’s a bijection.

1. You can use some basic linear algebra: show that $f$ is a linear transformation from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$, and show that the kernel (null space) of $f$ is trivial.
2. You can simply compute $f^{-1}$, thereby demonstrating that it exists and that $f$ is a bijection. If $f(a,b)=\langle 2,6\rangle$, say, what do $a$ and $b$ have to be? If you can answer that, you should be able to write down a general formula for $f^{-1}$.